# Uncaught ReferenceError: React360 is not defined (Its a matter of my Graduation. So I will be very grateful)

Tags: react-360

My react360 project was running fine. But I installed react-router-dom@5.0.2. After that my project didnt start. It gave this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCY5f.jpg)

My package.json file was :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9MOz.jpg)

After that I updated the react and react native versions. Now It is giving two errors:

1. error: client.js: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In C:\Users\Usman\test\node_modules\babel-preset-react-native\index.js
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: React360 is not defined

latest package.json:
"dependencies": {
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-360": "~1.1.0",
"react-360-web": "~1.1.0",
"react-native": "^0.68.2",
"three": "^0.87.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.1",
"jest": "^19.0.2",
"react-devtools": "^2.5.2",
"react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
"xopen": "1.0.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-360"
}

Answer (score 0):

Update: There is no solution to it. React 360 uses depreciated versions. Thus any new update changes packages. So you have to start again.